# Modify just one file in library

Tags: node.js

In node js, we import `require('library')` to use external library. let's say there's a `external-file.js` inside 'library' that we want to customise for our project. What is the technique that can be use? 
In Java, this can be done irreverently through just copying the external file and make sure it adhere to same package path. How can this be done in node.js ?

Comment: I think you can overwrite it (assume it as object) as desire before executing

Comment: Can provide example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally if this external library is getting pulled from npm or github, you should create a fork, use that in your project's package.json and modify the file in your own fork. Then when you commit the changes to the file, it'll go into your own version of the third party library. (And if the change is good enough you can even ask the author to incorporate it in their code and get credit for contributing to open source :D)

Additional benefit of doing it like this is that you won't have to commit the dependencies in along with your source code.

Comment: Let say only a minor changes that specifically not advantages to other users. How do I continue to use the external library and only need to change one file locally? Can provide example?

Comment: Again, still better to create a fork and use that in package.json. The change to the third party library is not a part of your code so it should not get checked into your code anyway.

Javascript is different from Java in that sense, it's not that easy to extend classes and modify what you need. To keep things clean, keep it separate as suggested before.